# How to change width of text-box using kendo-ui?

Tags: html, css, textbox, kendo-ui

I want two adjacent text boxes with different widths, using kendo-ui.

My HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox">1D22339</td>
    <td>12243JNJ3427676</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox.medium"><input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox.small"></td>
</tr>
```

My CSS:

```
.k-textbox.small{
    width: 20px;
}
.k-textbox.medium{
    width: 50px;
}
```

The problem is, both textboxes appear with the same (default) size. How may I correctly style the text-box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

HTML Code:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox">1D22339</td>
    <td>12243JNJ3427676</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="k-input k-textboxmedium">
        <input type="text" class="k-input k-textboxsmall"></td>
</tr>
```

CSS Code:

```
.k-textboxsmall{
    width: 20px !important; 
}
.k-textboxmedium{
    width: 50px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should like it-

```
input[type='text'].k-textbox.small{
    width: 20px;
}
input[type='text'].k-textbox.medium{
    width: 50px;
}
```

or

```
.k-textbox.small{
    width: 20px !important; 
}
.k-textbox.medium{
    width: 50px !important;
}
```

Hope it will helps you.